# Qt Creator + CMake header and source files separation

Tags: cmake, qt-creator

Is it possible for QtCreator to automatically create header files into ./include/%name of project%/ and source files into ./src/ directories?
By 'create' I mean Header Files -> right click -> Add New... -> C++ Class.
Currently QtCreator creates source and header files in project root directory (or both files in the specified directory), and it seems hard to separate header and source files manually.